# ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE= / mysql_convert_table_format WHICH IS BETTER

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have big InnoDB databases in MariaDB (> 1T each). I want to turn them to MyISAM. I can google 2 methods:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-convert-table-format.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

The second one is for InnoDB but the arg can be changed to MyISAM.

Which one is more efficient (I've installed the Perl modules mysql_convert_table_format needs)? Thank you!

Comment: The databases are fixed not, I only use SELECT later. Thanks for your sarcastic reasoning

Comment: You're right, there's no reason to throw pearls before swines I guess. I wish you all the best fun in Rome, love - Master race.

Comment: @N.B. Probably your reasoning is not sarcastic but it's wrong. `MyISAM` is not simply *slower* than `InnoDB`; it depends on the queries you run on it and the usage pattern. It is even faster on some operations because it doesn't support transactions and foreign keys and this eliminates the overhead associated with them. If the only queries that use a table are `SELECT`s and `INSERT`s (no `UPDATE`s, `DELETE`s) then `MyISAM` is the best engine one can get on `MySQL`.

Comment: @axiac - it's not faster in any case, especially for selects. We don't even have to argue about this, and on a terabyte data set - it won't be quicker at all. The reason it appears faster is because OS is able to schedule writes at a later stage since it's not ACID compliant. The reasons you mentioned are moot. So, my reasoning is not wrong, and in the end - I don't really care about your *opinion*, I prefer facts. Congratulations on teaching the future potential developers wrong facts. Ignorance is better than false knowledge.

Comment: @N.B. the *facts* are that we did the exact same conversion 4 years ago on a 2 billion records log table (the OP also mentions their data are activity logs in a comment to my answer) because accessing the `InnoDB` table was slowing down the site. Its performance rose immediately after we converted the table, the `MyISAM` version of the table now holds 3 billion records and it works just fine. Choosing one engine or another depends on the operations you do on the table and their usage patterns.

Comment: @axiac - let's just agree that we don't agree. You had positive results and I'm glad you did. The reason I posted a *comment* and not an answer was because I wanted to help the OP to get the best of both worlds - the performance and superior data compression but for some reason I was met with resistance, quite common for SO. I don't want to debate MyISAM vs InnoDB, factual state is that InnoDB lets us utilize hardware better, there are so many benchmarks out there and everyone can find what they want to satisfy their opinion. OP got his answer, it appears the universe is at ease again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql-convert-table-format` is just a tool that uses `ALTER TABLE` to do the job. It provides a nice interface and a help but other than that it doesn't do anything special.

You can use your favorite MySQL client program to connect to the database and run:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE='MyISAM'
```

to change the table format (this is what `mysql-convert-table-format` also does, in the end).

#### Warning!

During the changing of the table format, the table will be locked, i.e. inaccessible to other queries. This may translate to your site not responding, behaving strange or even being offline.

#### Other option

`pt-online-schema-change`, part of [`Percona Tookit`](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-tools/percona-toolkit), is a tool that aims to change the table definition of a large table while keeping it online. It creates a new table having the new structure then intelligently copies the data from the old table to the new table in chunks.

I didn't try it but I think it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation that they are the same in essence! The data are user activity logs and we've completed the data crawling for research analysis. Therefore the locking is not a big deal as we're not running applications for business. But still, thanks for the other option!

Comment: *"The data are user activity logs"* - you only run `INSERT`s and `SELECT`s on the table, it is the best use case for `MyISAM`. Another suggestion: use [`MERGE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/merge-storage-engine.html) storage engine and store the actual data in multiple yearly tables. This way you can easily remove the old records: drop then re-create the merge table. Of course, you have to implement the same flow to add new tables when the current time interval ends. We are using this workflow without merge tables (more work in the code) from 3 years ago and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks again for the introduction of the `MERGE` engine! Arrogant users think they met with resistance on SO because the users are lame. While they never think that they are not actually helping because they ignore others' questions but come with something else. Others' questions are not real questions because they know better. They like to remove the base of the question so the question doesn't exist anymore. I guess they'll never know why there's resistance everywhere.